# Error message: Invalid geometry Refactor Fields QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, vector, error, table

I'm trying to do a simple modification of changing field type to vector table by using the tool Refactor Fields. However, the output log returns the following error message, every time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\FieldsMapper.py", line 132, in processAlgorithm
return super().processAlgorithm(parameters, context, feeback)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Feature (18) has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option.

Execution failed after 0.17 seconds
```

It would be OK for me to ignore invalid input features, but there is no such option in the processing settings of this tool (see image). I'm using QGIS 3.6.1. Any suggestions?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Options > Settings > Processing and under General -> Invalid features processing select `Do not filter (better performance)` or `Skip (ignore) features with invalid geometries`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would consider fixing the bad geometries first, rather than having them lurking around for the refactoring, as well as any subsequent downstream operations.  Try the **Fix Geometies** tool.  I'm not sure when it was introduced, but it is available at 3.14.